# angular: ¿Cómo puedo acceder a cierta posición de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, map

Ayuda!! No se que estoy haciendo mal, soy bastante nueva programando, si alguien me indica porfacor
Recibo el siguiente objeto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero acceder a la posicion 1 de este, intente hacerlo asi:

//Variable que almacena la interfaz y le digo que las propiedades son obsionales

```
MapGoogleI: Partial<MapGoogleI> = {};

//Metodo que se suscribe al servicio
  LocToText() {
    //this.savedMarker?
    //variable que almacena una latitud
    const lat = this.savedMarker?.lat
    //variable que almacena una longitud
    const long = this.savedMarker?.lng
    //me suscribo a la peticion y formateo lat y long
    this.bookingService.formatedAdrress(lat, long).subscribe(res => {
      //Almaceno la res en la interfaz
      this.MapGoogleI = res;
      // mapeo el arreglo y lo posicion en la cero
      const formatted_address = this.MapGoogleI.results?.map(map => map.formatted_address[0]);
      //igualo
      this.formated_address = formatted_address;
      console.log('map', this.formated_address);
    }
    )
  }
```

//this.patientForm es el formulario reactivo y de alli llamo a this.formated_address para que me //inicie un input con el res de LocToText

```
  updateProfile() {
        this.patientForm.patchValue({
          address: this.formated_address
        });
      }
```

// Y lo obtengo de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El método `map` se ejecuta para cada valor de un array. Si solo quieres modificar el valor 0  no uses `map`, haz directamente `tuArray[0] = loquesea`. No tiene sentido iterar sobre todo el array si necesitas solo el primer valor. El valor que estás obteniendo es porque piensas que tu variable `map` tiene todo el objeto dentro, pero en realidad solo tiene un valor de cada vez, si es un array de 5 items lo que hace tu `map` es pasar por cada valor, iterando 5 veces sobre el array y guardando cada valor en la variable `map` que creas y que tú reasignas a la primera letra de dicho valor

Comment: Si, pero digamos es fácil en un arreglo como en la imagen, pero que tal y el arreglo viene asi:  let arreglo = [{ nombre: "Maggie", tipo: "Perro", edad: 3,}, { nombre: "Guayaba", tipo: "Perro", edad: 1,}, {nombre: "Snowball",tipo: "Gato", edad: 1,},]; Y yo quiero acceder a "Perro", solo a eso ¿cómo seria entonces?

Comment: Entonces no quieres acceder a la posición 1, quieres acceder a un valor concretro, da igual en que posición venga. Es muy diferente. Si lo único que quieres es obtener ese, `map` no te sirve, como dije antes, `map` recorre tu array entero mapeando(modificando) *CADA* elemento... lo que has de usar es [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): `arreglo.filter((element) => element.tipo === "Perro");`. Esto te devolverá un array con todos los elementos de tipo "Perro" que tengas.

Comment: Mostras el resultado un array de string pero de que? no veo clara  la estructura de acuerdo a lo que publicas de la resp del subscribe .En el ejemplo del comentario con
 const arryObjTipos=arreglo.map(obj=>({tipo:obj.tipo}));
 console.log(tipo) podes crear un array que solo contenga a los tipos y luego acceder a cada uno o hacer lo que quieras pero que es lo que queres hacer???